# GridPanel doesn't show store and filters

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, extjs5, gridpanel

I have a GridPanel with 5 columns, I put `filter:true` in every row but it doesn't show filter option and doesn't show the store items either, I see two rows but they are empty.

```
    storeSalvaguardas = [{'codigo':'10', 'tipoDocumento':'final','denominacion':'Documento de prueba', 'version':'2', 'descripcion':'eso'},{'codigo':'10', 'tipoDocumento':'final','denominacion':'Documento de prueba', 'version':'2', 'descripcion':'eso'}];

    grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: storeSalvaguardas,
        requires: [
                   'Ext.grid.filters.Filters'
               ],
        id: 'tablaGrid',
        trackMouseOver: true,
        columns: [
            {id:'codigo',header: '<bean:message key="label.agr.informes.codigo"/>', width: 10, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'codigo', filter: true},
            {id:'tDoc',header: '<bean:message key="label.gi.productos.tipo"/>', width: 10,sortable: true, dataIndex: 'tipoDocumento', filter: true},
            {id:'nombre',header: '<bean:message key="label.gestionRecursos.criterios.busqueda.tab1"/>', width: 15,sortable: true, dataIndex: 'denominacion', filter: true},
            {id:'version',header: '<bean:message key="label.gd.tab1.version"/>', width: 10,sortable: true, dataIndex: 'version', filter: true},
            {id:'descripcion',header: '<bean:message key="label.gd.tab3.anexos.columna.descripcion"/>', width: 55,sortable: false, dataIndex: 'descripcion', filter: true}
        ],
        bbar: [
            '<bean:message key="label.agr.dobleclic.modificar"/>'
        ],
        region: 'center',
        stripeRows: true,
        title:'<bean:message key="label.AGR.analisisgr.listadodocs"/>',
        frame:true,
        layout:'fit',
        border: true,
        loadMask: new Ext.LoadMask( Ext.getBody(), {
            msg:'<bean:message key="generic.label.cargando"/>'
        }), 
        forceFit: true,
        style: 'text-align: left;',
    });
```

Here is the result:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally only we needed to include `plugins: 'gridfilters',` in my code.

This is the final code:

```
grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            plugins: 'gridfilters',
            store: storeDocumento,
            listeners: {
                'rowdblclick': function (view, record, tr, columnIndex, e) {
                    var cell = e.getTarget('.x-grid-cell-inner');
                    if (!cell) {
                        return;
                    }
                var codigo = record.get('id_doc');

                alert('Codigo: ' + codigo);
            }
        },
        requires: [
                   'Ext.grid.filters.Filters'
               ],
        id: 'tablaGrid',
        trackMouseOver: false,
        columns: [
            {id:'id_doc',header: '', width: 10, sortable: true,  dataIndex: 'id_doc', filter: 'string', hidden: true},
            {id:'codigo',header: '<bean:message key="label.agr.informes.codigo"/>', width: 10, sortable: true,  dataIndex: 'codigo', filter: 'string'},
            {id:'tDoc',header: '<bean:message key="label.gi.productos.tipo"/>', width: 10,sortable: true, dataIndex: 'tipoDocumento', filter: 'list'},
            {id:'nombre',header: '<bean:message key="label.gestionRecursos.criterios.busqueda.tab1"/>',  dataIndex: 'denominacion',  width: 15,sortable: true,  filter: true},
            {id:'version',header: '<bean:message key="label.gd.tab1.version"/>', width: 10,sortable: true,  dataIndex: 'version', filter: 'number'},
            {id:'fecha',header: 'Fecha', width: 10, sortable: true,   dataIndex: 'fecha', filter: 'date'},
            {id:'descripcion',header: '<bean:message key="label.gd.tab3.anexos.columna.descripcion"/>', width: 55, dataIndex: 'descripcion', sortable: false, filter: false}
        ],
        bbar: [
            '<bean:message key="label.agr.dobleclic.modificar"/>'
        ],
        region: 'center',
        stripeRows: true,
        title:'<bean:message key="label.AGR.analisisgr.listadodocs"/>',
        frame:true,
        layout:'fit',
        border: true,
        loadMask: new Ext.LoadMask( Ext.getBody(), {
            msg:'<bean:message key="generic.label.cargando"/>'
        }), 
        forceFit: true,
        style: 'text-align: left;',
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe filtering is applied at the [Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092549/gridpanel-dont-show-store-and-filters) level.

Here is a snippet from the documentation, with an example:

> **Filtering and Sorting**
>
> Stores can be sorted and filtered - in both cases either remotely or
>   locally. The sorters and filters are held inside MixedCollection
>   instances to make them easy to manage. Usually it is sufficient to
>   either just specify sorters and filters in the Store configuration or
>   call sort or filter:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     model: 'User',
     sorters: [{
         property: 'age',
         direction: 'DESC'
     }, {
         property: 'firstName',
         direction: 'ASC'
     }],

     filters: [{
         property: 'firstName',
         value: /Ed/
     }]
 });
```

> The new Store will keep the configured sorters and filters in the
>   MixedCollection instances mentioned above. By default, sorting and
>   filtering are both performed locally by the Store - see remoteSort and
>   remoteFilter to allow the server to perform these operations instead.
>
> Filtering and sorting after the Store has been instantiated is also
>   easy. Calling filter adds another filter to the Store and
>   automatically filters the dataset (calling filter with no arguments
>   simply re-applies all existing filters).

```
store.filter('eyeColor', 'Brown');
```

The [Column](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column) object does not seem to have a filter property so I do not think you can do it that way.

I usually create a form above or at the side of the grid with filter options for particular fields. Here is an [Example](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.1/examples/grid/filtered-buffered-store.html).